# Error !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a project that recognizes faces from a video camera. But every time I run the code, it throws an error.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read('f_Denis.yml')
cascade = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade)

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX

names = ['Not found', 'Denis']

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(10, 10))

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])

        if (confidence < 100):
            id_obj = names[1]
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))
        else:
            id_obj = names[0]
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))

        cv2.putText(img, str(id_obj), (x + 5, y - 5), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(confidence), (x + 5, y - 5), font, 1, (255, 255, 0), 1)


        cv2.imshow('Face Recognation', img)

        k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            break

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After reading about this on the Internet, I realized that this error is due to the fact that the data from the camera is not transferred to the img variable, as if the video camera is not connected.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/idlelib/run.py", line 578, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "/home/andrey/Загрузки/Face_rec (1)/Face_rec/face_detect.py", line 21, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:196: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

But I have it connected and works great. Even when I display the img variable, I see various numbers in the console, which, as I understand it, are related to the position and color of the pixels (possibly). Perhaps I made some kind of mistake, but I don’t understand what, because the code seems to be written correctly, and I don’t understand how this error occurs. **How can I fix it?**

I have already tried many ways to fix this error. I reconnected the video camera, reinstalled the libraries and even launched it on other systems, but nothing helped.

Comment: What does `img` contain? What are those "various numbers"? Also you forgot to check the `ret` value to see whether the image frame fetching even succeeded!

Comment: Seems like your image is empty. At least, this is what the error is telling you. Is `ret` true?

Comment: If I try to set the img and ret variables(adding line: "print(img, "\n", ret)"), the result will be as follows:
...

 [[106  64  41]
  [106  64  41]
  [104  62  44]
  ...
  [223 240 222]
  [221 241 222]
  [220 240 220]]

 [[112  66  42]
  [111  65  41]
  [103  63  40]
  ...
  [219 241 222]
  [219 241 222]
  [219 241 222]]

 [[105  63  47]
  [104  62  46]
  [ 99  61  45]
  ...
  [223 242 218]
  [222 246 224]
  [218 241 219]]] 
 True

Then it waits a bit and doesn’t output anything, and then I see this: "None 
 False" and error

Comment: When you say _waits a bit_, how much does it wait? In fact, how many iterations are you achieving? One?

Comment: The word "True" is repeated three times, and then the word "False" (variable ret). The first time it waits 40 seconds before making an error. Second time right away.